# how do i stop the invalid code message repeating while also occuring at the right time

Tags: python

I am writing a program to search a txt file for a certain line based only on part of the string. If the string isn't found, it should print not found once, but it is printing it multiple times. Even after indenting and using a correct code it still prints:

Comment: Reindent your `else` block to match up with your `if` one

Answer (score 1):

the else suite is executed after the for terminates normally (not by a break).
so it will definitely execute the else statement in your code, because you don't break in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong indentation with the else, this is the right code:

```
num = raw_input("Type Number : ")
search = open("TableOfProducts.txt","r")
for line in search.readlines():
    if num in line:
        print line
    else:
        print ("invalid code. ")
        break
```

The reason this didn't throw an error is because `for` loops can also have an `else` block that only gets shown if there is no elements in the loop.

Comment: this did throw and error as it printed invalid code multiple times instead of one, that was my problem, it was running through the whole file.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using `try`/`except`. In this way, you can provide the "invalid" message if the above code fails to find a match. See below.

```
num = raw_input("Type Number: ")
with open('TableOfProducts.txt', "r") as search:
    for line in search.readlines():
        if num in line:
            goodline = line
try:
    print goodline
except:
    print "Invalid code."
```

The reason it keeps repeating is because the code will check every line, and as long as there's no match, for every line that doesn't match it will print "invalid code" (even if it has already found one)

PS: Unless you use `with`, as shown above, make sure you put `search.close()` at the end